# How to Select All Checkboxes By ID

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, checkbox

when user clicks check all first, second checkbox should be unchecked and vice versa, for now everything is checked.

What I'm trying to do is get something to select all checkboxes. But what works is currently selected not all by id, I want to do it based on $item->payroll_group_id

my code in index.blade.php

```
     @foreach ($unit as $item)
          @if ($item->payroll_group_id == null || $item->payroll_group_id == $payroll_id)
                                <tr class='employee-row'>
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" class="emp-check" id="check" name="employee_id[]" value="{{ $item->employee_id }}">
                                    <input type="hidden" class="py-sid" value="{{ $item->payroll_group_id }}"></td>
                                    <td class='captial'>{{ $item->name }}</td>
                                    <td class='captial'>{{ $item->position ?? '-' }}</td>
                                </tr>
              @endif
     @endforeach
```

Here is the javascript for this

```
<script>
    function toggle(source) {
        var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[id="check"]');
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            if (checkboxes[i] != source)
                checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
        }
    }
</script
```

how to solve my problem please help me.

Comment: first point you should avoid having same id for multiple checkboxes. Embed index or something according to requirement to id to make unique

Comment: i am confused how to embed an index or something for the id to make it unique because its inside a loop.

Comment: add $index=0 before the loop and then  do this <input type="checkbox" class="emp-check" id="check-{{$index++}}" name="employee_id[]" value="{{ $item->employee_id }}"